# How to use the function Predict[] with variable-length dataset?

Tags: rule, machine-learning

I can use the function Predict[] with pre-defined dataset successfully.

```
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}^3;
p = Predict[A]
```

However, when the length of dataset is unknown. How can I to build the dataset in runtime?

e.g.

```
(* There are 125 items, the length is unknown until runtime *)
data = {123.5, 123,1, 123.2, 123.3, 123.6,......}  

(* "Argument {1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729} should be a rule or a list of rules" *)
p = predict[data]
```

Please feel free to comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you want to provide to a `Predict` assuming you have `data = {1.1, 2.1, 3.1}` and assuming the length of `data` isn't known a priori.

Comment: Predict[] is a build-in function. (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Predict.html)

Comment: I know, my question was what do you want to put there as an argument.

Comment: e.g. there are 125 items, A = {1,2,3,4,5,.....,125}->{123.5, 123,1, 123.2, 123.3, 123.6,......,160.123} , how to build the array with "->" rules.

Comment: Like `(Range@Length@# -> #) &@data`?

Comment: Predict[] doesn't accept a vector directly, it seems it accepts a vector with "->" only. Am I correct? Please feel free to comment.

Comment: It seems so and it is what I gave you. Don't know much about predict though.

Comment: @Kuba, Thank you. It seems the problem has been resolved. B = (Range@Length@# -> #) &@data[[All, 2]];